# Why is my UI Button working but not animating or indicating to the user?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have added a UI Button inside of a stack view which is inside of a table view in my storyboard. When I click on my button the correct output is printed in my debugger console but there is no indication in the app that the button has been clicked (no default animation). I have tried looking at my view hierarchy and changing all of the parent views to clip to bounds. Any idea why the button is functioning but not being animated to the user?

Comment: Post your code so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix to your problem is to set `delaysContentTouches = false` for your table view.

According to the Apple Docs,

> If the value of this property is true, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. If the value is false, the scroll view immediately calls touchesShouldBegin(_:with:in:). The default value is true.
>   See the class description for a fuller discussion.

---

Alternatively, if you have subclassed the UIScrollView, you can get the same thing done by overriding the following function,

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        return type(of: view) == UIButton.self
    }

}
```